# No compara bien los string (creo). Java CompareTo()

Tags: java, string, comparaciones

Pues tengo un problema y no entiendo por que no compara bien el valor de los string. Agradeceria toda la ayuda posible. Al no repartir bien los "numeros" (pasados como string). el string final es mas grande que un long y da error.

EDIT: 

Lo que hace es ir metiendo los Integers almacenados en conjuntoNumeros en dos strings, no busco que se sumen, si no que se repartan por valor equitativamente, es decir: Si en conjuntoNumeros tengo 9,9,6,5,5,3,2,1.  Los strings deberian quedar así como:

s1= 9 5 5 1

s2= 9 6 3 2

No es una suma de los propios numeros, si no que va repartiendo entre los dos strings

No se si me he explicado bien, el `compareTo` deberia de darme `1` si esto fuera asi: `"23".compareTo("15")`, no?

Aqui el fragmento de codigo que me da error:

```
long[] solucion = new long[2];
int c; //candidato
String cs;

while (!(conjuntoNumeros.isEmpty())){
    //seleccionar candidato
    c = seleccionarCandidato(conjuntoNumeros);
    //eliminar candidato
    conjuntoNumeros.remove(new Integer(c));
    cs = String.valueOf(c);
    if (s1.compareTo(s2)>=1){
        s2 = s2 + cs;
    }else{
        s1 = s1 + cs;
    }
}
System.out.println(s1 + " y " + s2);
solucion[0]=new Long(s1).longValue();
solucion[1]=new Long(s2).longValue();

return solucion;
```

**cs** es el string del int que saco en la funcion seleccionar candidato

**conjuntoNumeros** es un arrayList que contiene integers

La idea del codigo es que reparta equitativamente y acaben los dos numeros o iguales o que esten muy cercanos entre si.

Aquí el codigo de seleccionar candidato:

Esta funcion busca el numero más grande almacenado en el Arraylist de conjuntoNumeros.

```
int seleccionarCandidato(ArrayList<Integer> conjunto){
    int candidato = conjunto.get(0);

    for (int i=1; i<conjunto.size(); i++){
        if(candidato < conjunto.get(i)) candidato = conjunto.get(i);
    }
    return candidato;
}
```

Y por ultimo el codigo de error:

Me da error por que creo que el tamaño del string es muchisimo mayor y deberia de ser siempre menor(si se repartiera bien).

codigo del error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9998777666655555554433322111"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
at java.lang.Long.<init>(Long.java:965)
at NumeroMasCercanos.VorazNumerosCercanos(NumeroMasCercanos.java:55)
at Pruebas.main(Pruebas.java:12)
```

Comment: Para comparar strings utiliza el Equals: string1.Equals(string2), aunque no creo que venga de ahí el error

Comment: Por favor explica mejor el propósito de estas 3 sentencias: `s1.compareTo(s2)>=1`, `s2 = s2 + cs;` y `s1 = s1 + cs;`. Hay que entender bien lo que pretender lograr con estas sentencias. Cuando dices *La idea del codigo es que reparta equitativamente*, esto no es lo suficientemente claro.

Comment: Tu problema es que cuando haces s2 + cs o s1 + cs, al guardarlo en un string, la funcion + acumula.
Por ejemplo, si tu haces "hola" + "mundo", tu string sera "holamundo". lo que está sucediendo es eso. prueba que cs, s1 y s2 sean integers o long directamente.

Comment: Con tu última edición, 1) Toma en cuenta que el uso `compareTo` con 2 strings va a hacer una comparación alfabética, no numérica. 2) Tu intención sí parece ser de ir concatenando/acumulando varios números en las variables `s1` y `s2`. De ser el caso, no entiendo porque después tratas de convertirlo a un `Long` como si se tratara de un solo número. Te soy franco, seré un poco lento, pero aun no entiendo del todo tu objetivo.

Comment: @sstan nada nada, no te preocupes, no se explicarme muy bien, la idea es concatenarlos, pero, a la vez, una vez concatenados sean un numero. como decirlo... si tengo dos 9 lo que quiero es un 99 y no un 18. podria usar otra cosa para compararlo mejor? en plan por tamaños, pasarlo a un int y comparar o algo así?

Comment: Tal vez no sea una comparación lo que necesitas. Como hablas de querer repartir la lista de forma equitativa, tal vez lo que quieres es simplemente alternar la variable a la que le asignas el resultado de `seleccionarCandidato`. O sea, la primera vez le asignas a `s1`, la segunda a `s2`, la tercera a `s1`, `s2`, `s1`, etc... ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser que no comprendes como funciona el compareTo.

El compareTo trabaja comparando un string byte por byte (caracter por caracter), basándose en el codigo ASCCI, te retorna un valor cuando encuentra el primer caracter diferente en toda la cadena (el valor que te retorna es la diferencia de bits)

Si bien tienes razón con respecto a que
**"23".compareTo("15")** te dará un 1.
Te falta analizar que pasa despues,
entonces el siguiente valor (supongamos que es 2) se guardara en **s2** por lo cual quedara de la siguiente forma **s1="23"    s2="215"**

volverá a seleccionar un candidato y supongamos que es el 1
¿En donde crees que lo guardara?

Hara de nuevo un compareTo de la siguiente manera
**"23".compareTo("215")**
leera byte a byte 2=2 por lo que seguira con el siguiente,
3 != 1 te devolvera un 2 por que 3 es 2 bits mas grande que 1
entonces volvera a entrar en el if y volvera a añadir el numero en **s2** por lo que ahora tendras **s2="1215"   y   s1="23"**
y si llegaras a tener otro valor se volvera a guardar en **s2**.

**Solucion**

antes de hacer el compareTo compara el tamaño de las cadenas con length();
de esta manera podras ingresar el valor en la cadena mas pequeña y cuando sean iguales entonces si recurrira al compare To

**Solucion 2**

personalmente la considero mas optima, utilizas un metodo de ordenación para ordenar tu array de numeros y posteriormente asignas los indices pares del array a s1 y los impares a s2 e incluso nisiquiera es necesario pasarlo por string los vas guardando directamente en un long si multiplicas por unidades, decenas, centenas etc.

**Nota**

me di cuenta que estas asignando

s2 = s2 + cs

o s1= s1 + cs

yo te lo explique como si estuvieras guardando

s2 = cs + s2

s1 = cs + s1

Esto no cambia en nada la lógica que te acabo de explicar por que si en algún momento tienes s2 = 2 y s1 = 1 siempre se guardara en s2 ya que el 2 y el 1 seran siempre los primeros digitos que se comparen.

A lo que iba es que el objetivo es el de formar 2 números con la menor diferencia posible.

esto implica que si tienes 998761 la mejor manera sera guardando al final de la cadena de manera que obtengas

s1=986 y s2=971 de lo contrario obtendrías una diferencia mas grande s1=179 y s2=689

pero si tienes 943211 lo ideal seria guardarlo a principio  de la cadena para obtener

s1=124 s2=139 de lo contrario obtendiras una diferencia mas grande s1=421 s2=931

sin duda es un problema interesante

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas. Primero, para el caso de la excepción, ocurre porque estás intentando convertir el texto `9998777666655555554433322111` en un `long`, pero el máximo número que alcanza a almacenar un `long` es `9223372036854775807`. Lo que podrías hacer para solucionar este problema es cambiar el retorno de la solución para que sea un texto, algo así:

```
String solucion = new String[2];
//...
solucion[0] = s1;
solucion[1] = s2;
return solucion;
```

*Nota: Esta parte no es realmente importante si tienes certeza que los resultados siempre podrán ser convertidos en un `long`*

Por otro lado, `compareTo` compara alfabéticamente, es decir que si en algún momento comparas `9` contra `12345`, `9` parecerá mayor. Sin embargo, podrías fijarte en la longitud de las cadenas (si hay una cadena más corta que la otra, tiene un menor valor), además de utilizar el `compareTo`. Sería algo así:

```
int largoS1 = s1.length();
int largoS2 = s2.length();
if (largoS2<largoS1 || largoS1==largoS2 && s1.compareTo(s2)>=1){
    s2 = s2 + cs;
}else{
    s1 = s1 + cs;
}
```

Aquí tienes un [ejemplo funcional del código](https://tio.run/##fVRNj9owED2XX@FyWNliG0i2nwJWqqoeKlXtSvSGOHgdkzV17Mh2WFGW307txAkhmPUICXnevPE8P2eDt/idLKjYpH@PR5YXUhmwsZtRaRiPviqFdz@ZNtNBOKenA8Kx1uBBlfQR7wfALm2wYQS0xbMfwtCMqntApNiUwshfZU6V1GAOBH0OACGadpkWRjGRAR3bguEwmEo6qaJ85DblEVvJUpBjJqDHYpXp5QrtB2@YMMsVEO1h9vGti8TGXRXvbXw4i48@PlXx@fZLHYe6s1trqaAlBmw@mQI28@wRpyIzT3ZnNEL7FuxWT5QIpyn0VUu2QifmQ/uPYE5KjtVC8pIwKRq9DpfS2AEv0acDtCDtk/5O/H6yOrV3Q5EpGI8JFilLsZE9FkCsHdq95yfGKYBvYX8@pr/nhdlBhHpCjMeackrcKbACl12qye35OqhvDajfpSNbTU05y9krvL1DKprLLYVOCm9KSFCPlDjP1KNHW8xL@nttQecYJ5qVPpMLZ14dex/AqzBnZJ1cg60B9LBZw/ry0jSYzxuKmxvXisi8wIr@kVAn6H4e9@SurFK3A6Pq7rqZA@WaBgrqMUIFAZ8udtrQPJKliQork@ECVrVDsLO/ke3cGbBx4HKyqnoEMnGVSTouU9SUSrSIwDNw0gYd88r3qaNU5fqmxnZvIFFGDZygzlHswwf@5cfu5bdIzf5Re5OBp8@sYVru2Tk3Q@h6Yxb8LHgx2qpGjcPx@B8)

Answer (score 0):

El detalle se refiere a la longitud del numero que es mas grande de lo que puede soportar el int

> c = seleccionarCandidato(conjuntoNumeros);

int
Entero
4 bytes
2*10^9

Estas superando esta capacidad.

Revisa el tido de dato **double**

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger[] solucion = new BigInteger[2];



 solucion[0]=new BigInteger(s1);
 solucion[1]=new BigInteger(s2);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leas [answer], igual si explicas tu aporte les será mas fácil comprender como soluciona la pregunta expuesta

Answer (score -1):

El número es muy grande para que lo puedes guardar en un Long, te recomiendo que uses `BigInteger` para esos casos.

```
BigInteger[] solucion = new BigInteger[2];



 solucion[0]=new BigInteger(s1);
 solucion[1]=new BigInteger(s2);
```